# How to run scripts from within eclipse

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, makefile, automake

I have a project that doesn't use autotools, but has a Makefile which I run to build the code. This make file is run from within in a shell script. I have imported the project in eclipse, but I can't seem to run the shell script (Something like Ctrl + B to Make or add one of the Make targets viz., make all or make install).

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a script to build your project in *Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Build Command -> Builder Settings*.

You can uncheck *Use default build command* and specify yours (e.g. `make all`, `make install` or `bash make_all.sh`). Or you can leave the default build command (it must be `make`) and in tab *Behaviour* specify targets.

But before you should have imported your project *Makefile Project with Existing Code*.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Eclipse if you are using Make tools in the same project. Eclipse brings you some tools for project compiling, etc. that you already have with Make/Automake.